# Passing a string variable to glob

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I'm trying to pass a directory to glob which will be read to a variable from a config file.

If I just do this it works fine:

```
path = '//Server/Company/Official Documents/**/*.pdf'
Files = glob.glob(path,recursive=True)
```

But if I try to do this I get an empty list:

```
path = Config[1][1]
Files = glob.glob('{path}**/*.pdf'.format(path=path),recursive=True)
```

For information,

```
print(Config [1][1])
```

gives this

```
'//Server/Company/Official Documents/'
```

Comment: Print this and check if it's equal to what you expect it to be `'{path}**/*.pdf'.format(path=path)`

Answer (score 1):

You are missinng **/** in '{path}**/*.pdf'.format(path=path)
Try changinng it to:

```
'{path}/**/*.pdf'.format(path=path1)

like:

glob.glob('{path}/**/*.pdf'.format(path=path),recursive=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong in my question, that slash is included in the string from the config file, so sadly it's still not working.